# Does basinhopping of scipy changes stepsize randomly or adaptively, by default?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy

I am confused about the ‘take_step’ option in `scipy.optimize.basinhopping`:

According to the [online reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html):

> The default step taking routine is a random displacement of the
>   coordinates ... take_step can optionally have the attribute
>   `take_step.stepsize`. If this attribute exists, then basinhopping will
>   adjust `take_step.stepsize` in order to try to optimize the global
>   minimum search.

According to the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py#L302) (line 587, see below), however,  `scipy`’s `basinhopping` uses  `AdaptiveStepSize` by default, and  adjusts `stepsize` to something like 0.9*stepsize or stepsize/0.9, etc., regardless of whether `take_step.stepsize` is specified.

```
# use default
displace = RandomDisplacement(stepsize=stepsize)
take_step_wrapped = AdaptiveStepsize(displace, interval=interval,
verbose=disp)
```

Thus, my understanding from reading the source of `basinhopping` is, by default, the procedure will adaptively modify the default `stepsize` (0.5) to some stepsize * factor, stepsize/factor, etc., following how many samplings have been accepted in the Metropolis-Hasting procedure. I am confused because the online reference of `basinhopping`, on the other hand,  seems to indicate that the default `stepsize` will be something totally random.

Can anyone clarify? If I do *not* provide any `take_step` procedure to `basinhopping`, then will it try with `stepsize` randomly, or will it modify `stepsize` adaptively? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The step size is adaptively updated by default.  The only time it is not updated is if you pass a custom take_step object which does not have an attribute called `stepsize`